# open source "Performance testing and Load Testing" tools for web application

Tags: performance, testing, load

can any one suggest me best open source "Performance testing and Load Testing" tools for web application performance and load testing. My web app has been developed using PHP and ExtJs. any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [open source Tool for stress testing, load testing and performance testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507683/open-source-tool-for-stress-testing-load-testing-and-performance-testing)

Comment: Open source as "i intend to modify the source" or open source as "I have no intention of paying for a license..."  It makes a difference as the latter includes some commercial and freeware tools up to a specific load level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is the one I use. It's very flexible, can be scaled to generate huge load if required, and there are "cloud" services to offload the infrastructure requirements if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) - this is an open source framework that allows you to run many load testing tools such as JMeter, Grinder, Gatling, Apache Benchmark and more. The cool thing about Taurus is that you get the functionality of each of these open sources tools and you can easily create the test scenarios using YAML or JSON formats!